# Cannot implicitly convert type int to int array

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, compiler-errors, int

I have simple method. I can't figure out why it throws an error. Thanks in advance!

```
 public static int[] Shift(int[] a) 
 {    
       if (a == null) return -1;
       ...
 }
```

Compiler throws the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `int` to `int[]`

Comment: The value -1 is not an int array so cannot be returned as an int array.

Comment: How could I return int array? I just started whit C# tutorials..

Comment: if a== null is an error condition, you could throw an exception or you could return null

Comment: change the method signature to return an 'int`

Comment: For what it's worth, there's a really good article on debugging available [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) if you're just starting out.

Comment: @MethodMan That's a bad solution. This is the null handling for Mario's code, return type is set by what the successful execution returns, not the error handling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if your array is null you are returning an int. The function is expecting an int[]. You can return null or a blank array.

Comment: How would this example look like in code? I'm begginer and really having hard time figuring out.

Comment: Given [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769644/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-int-to-int-array#comment72654940_42769644) you may want to include a couple of examples to show *how* to return null or an empty array.  Otherwise, this is a great answer: concise and to the point.

Comment: public static int[] Shift(int[] a) 
 {    
       if (a == null) return null;
       ...
 }

or 

public static int[] Shift(int[] a) 
 {
      int[] result;
       if (a == null) return result;
       ...
 }

Comment: or return new int[0];

Comment: So its not possible to return -1?

Comment: This will help you with all your array questions : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You will want to return new int[1](-1)

Comment: ^Thats stays you are creating a new array with one space, In that space put -1

Comment: You shouldn't send empty array's unless you can help it. But if you have to check you could see if the return array is null instead of array[0] = -1; or if the array is empty array.length > 0;

Comment: @Mario Do you mean null? There is a difference between "null" and an empty array. And I would argue that design-wise, returning null would be the better choice.

Comment: @Mario Consider the intention of this method. It returns a copy of the source array with all of its elements shifted. In the case of `null`, it makes no sense to shift a `null`, so just return `null. With an empty array, there are no elements to shift, so return an empty array.

Comment: @Mario An alternative that I would suggest is to treat the parameter array as `ref` and avoid returning anything. That way you can manipulate the source array directly and not have to worry about allocating an entirely new array every time you call this method. (Unless copying the array is your intention, of course.)

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to return and int but your method requires an array of ints.
What do you want to return in this case?

You could return an empty array

```
return new int[]{};
```

or an array which contains -1

```
return new int[]{-1};
```

Comment: This seems like a comment more than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int[] Shift(int[] a) 
 {    
       if (a == null) return null;
       ...
 }
```

or

```
 public static int[] Shift(int[] a) 
 {    
       if (a == null) return new int[]{};
       ...
 }
```

Because your `static` method is defined as having an `int[]` return type, your return type must be an int array, not an int. Like any object, this can be `null` but depending on your usage, an empty array may be better, to avoid a null reference exception at the caller.